# Anyone using Naiant Gear?

Tags: microphone, pre-amp

I'm thinking of getting the new Naiant Littlebox when it comes out and am considering picking up a mic or two of theirs. Has anyone here used any of the Naiant gear and what do you think about it?

http://www.naiant.com/naiant.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to bump this thread, but im surprised you have got no answers on this yet!

I bought these:

[image]
<sub>(source: [naiant.com](http://www.naiant.com/images/240_X-S_480.JPG))</sub>

X-S Miniature Omnidirectional Condenser Microphone, with XLR adaptor cable & windscreen, each, $39

I was really impressed with the sound from these little fellas.

I have used the X-S Miniatures on my acoustic guitar through a Profire2626 and got quite a nice sound.

I think for sound design use its great to have some of these around as extra mics, It could be useful to use them in situations where you wouldn't want to use a really expensive mic (i.e. somewhere near explosions etc) as the loss of one wouldn't be the end of the world financially. or as extra angles on sources if you have the inputs?

Saying that though, they are hand built with lots of obviously lots of care and attention and I'd feel awful using them as if they were disposable :(

Comment: Thanks for that. Ended up not getting anything from them, but may do so in the future. 

How's the handling noise on your Naiant mics? In terms of using them as a disposable mic, I wonder how they compare to the Oktavas. For effects recordings, I know people use the Oktavas MK-012 as a alternative to their Schoeps so they won't feel too much of a heartache if it blows.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting stuff, never seen them before. Dirt cheap and some models have a pretty decent noise level as well. Probably not the best mics one could ver own and not the straightest frequency curve I've seen. But hey most of them cost around 50$. At that price it really isn't worth the hassle of doing DIY disposable mics.

So how do they sound?

Comment: Ill do a recording session and get back to you with some samples :)